# snr calculation of frame

Tags: matlab, opencv

I have to calculate SNR of an image. I have camera through which continuous images are getting generated, my requirement is to calculate the SNR in db for each image.
I have seen lot of the examples where they have added a noise to image then computed the SNR value.
I have to calculate SNR of each image independently without adding any noise.
please help.

Comment: Define what is signal in your image, and define what is noise. Calculate the energy in each component, and divide them. That's your SNR.  We can't tell you what is signal and what is noise. Only you can define that, as it will depend on what the camera is taking pictures of.

Comment: thankyou very much.
can you please elaborate little bit on how can i define signal and what is noise in image.
i am beginner in image processing.

Comment: Suppose your image should be always the same. Take 10 copies of the image. Average them. That's your signal.  Take an 11th image. Subtract the "signal" we just calculated. The subtraction is your noise.

Comment: thanks  ,but i have a requirement to calculate snr and lux of an I image to satisfy a table given as lux = 0.1-1 1-50 50-100 snr = 25 dB 30 dB 40dB.
i have video input as a source.
please show some way ,got fully busted with this implementation.
any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some data to help? A couple of example frames (images) might give me more of a clue as to how to answer.